# Write access violation when initializing pointer

Tags: c++, directx-11, access-violation, nullptr

I am getting a write access violation when attempting to dynamically create an array, it seems as like the memory address at which the pointer is stored is invalid.

Header:

```
struct FontType
{
    float left;
    float right;
    float size;
}

FontType* m_Font = nullptr;
```

Source:

```
m_Font = new FontType[60];
```

The error message reads:

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
this was nullptr.
```

Running

```
std::cout << &m_Font << std::endl;
```

returns different addresses such as 00000000 or 00000004 which I believe is the problem but I don't know how to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If `m_Font` is a pointer, `&m_Font` is the address of the storage that pointer occupies, not the address that pointer points to.

Comment: I think the problem is that are allocating a pointer to an array of 60 of them...

Comment: It seems like whereever you are calling `m_Font = new FontType[60];` the `this` pointer is `nullptr`. You are calling a member function using a `nullptr`. The problem lies outside of the code you've shown. This is why producing a [MCVE] is important.

Comment: The error happens even when I call m_Font = new FontType();

Comment: `m_Font` is a member of some object being accessed via some pointer or reference. The problem is, there is no "there" there regarding that pointer or reference. You have not posted where `m_Font` actually *resides*. It appears to be a member variable. Always **always** post any code needed to copy/paste/produce your problem. We can't do that, so a guess is the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Version**

The object you're accessing via pointer or reference which *contains* the `m_Font` member is invalid.

---

**Long Version**

Somewhere in the annals of your unposted code is some class, `Foo`, that has a member `FontType *m_Font;` Somewhere you have this:

```
struct FontType
{
    float left;
    float right;
    float size;
};

struct Foo
{
    FontType *m_Font;

    Foo() : m_Font(nullptr)
    {
    }

    void bar()
    {
        m_Font = new FontType();
    }
};
```

The use of naked pointers notwithstanding (bad idea), the problem stems from somewhere *else* in your (still) unposted code, that looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    Foo *pf = nullptr;

    pf->bar(); // BAD - dereferencing an invalid pointer
}
```

If you think the `nullptr` is the problem above, let me assure you this is equally invalid:

```
int main()
{
    Foo *pf;

    pf->bar(); // BAD - dereferencing an indeterminate pointer
}
```

In short, the memory allocation within the `bar()` member isn't the problem. Rather, it's the storage of the resulting pointer to a member of a non-existent/invalid object that *is* the problem, and is a direct result of attempting to use an invalid pointer or reference to an object that actually *isn't* an object.

The best evidence of this is divulged in the item you posted near the end, trying to print the address of the member itself. You said this:

```
std::cout << &m_Font << std::endl;
```

seemed to print null, sometimes 4, etc.

According to the C++ standard, class type members (such as your `m_Font`) reside in addressable space at some potentially padded location from the base of the containing object. There can be padding between, and even after, but *never* before the first member. Therefore, if `m_Font` is the first member of the `Foo` class, then all of the addresses below are equivalent:

```
&m_Font == &this->m_Font == this
```

per the requirement that the first member cannot have padding before it and the address of the containing object is equivalent to the address of its first member.

What all of that means is that `this` must be equivalent to `nullptr`, in the context of the code that is performing `std::cout << &m_Font` and producing a null pointer for output,  assuming `m_Font` is the first member (in fact it must be if null is indeed the printed output).